# Is there a way to plot multiple horizontal lines using hlines() function in a single plot of matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot, horizontal-line

I have an **pm2_5** dataframe data which I've plotted using a `matplotlib scatterplot`.
I want to insert multiple horizontal lines at different *y-values*,
I'm doing it by manually calling the '''ax.axhline''' function for each different value of **y**. Is there any way to automate the whole process?

```py
# making a graph with delineated health levels of pm2.5 in the year 2015
fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7));
pm2_5.plot(kind='scatter',x='S_no',y='pm2_5',c='pm2_5',ax=ax, cmap='tab20b');
ax.axhline(y=150,linestyle ='--')
ax.axhline(y=100,linestyle ='--')
ax.axhline(y=200,linestyle ='--')
ax.axhline(y=300,linestyle ='--')
```

Here is how it should look like:
[image]

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
[ax.axhline(y=i, linestyle='--') for i in [150,100,200,300]]
```

Comment: thanks man i was thiking in the same way but could'nt figureout the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Correcting the above answer to remove the spelling mistake...

`[ax.axhline(y=i, linestyle='--') for i in [150,100,200,300]]`